How to Adjust Thumbnail Content Size in MacOS Quick Look Plugin Using JavaScript?
I'm trying to fix an issue with a Quick Look plugin where thumbnails are generated using JavaScript in the thumbnail.html file. The problem is that the content doesn't scale properly to fit the thumbnail size.
How can I access the actual dimensions of the thumbnail within the JavaScript code in thumbnail.html to adjust the content accordingly? Any advice or code examples would be greatly appreciated!
Here is the code of thumbnail.html:


<html>
    <head>
        <script language='javascript'>%@</script>
        <script language='javascript'>%@</script>
        <script language='javascript'>var data =[%@];</script>
        <style>
                    body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: 'Century Gothic';
            
        }
            #previewGraph{
                border: 5px solid #2955ff;
                width: 90% !important;
                height: 90% !important;

            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='previewGraph'></div>
        <script>
            var domGraph = document.getElementById('previewGraph');
            var graphinstance = new Graph(domGraph);
            graphinstance.resize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
            graphinstance.newSerie('serieTest').autoAxis() .setData(data);
            graphinstance.getXAxis().setAxisDataSpacing(0,0);
            graphinstance.getYAxis().setAxisDataSpacing(0,0);
            graphinstance.getYAxis().setDisplay(false);
            graphinstance.getXAxis().setDisplay(false);
            graphinstance.redraw();
            graphinstance.drawSeries();
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>



I tried different options by setting css, element style without success...

I feel you could share a little of your code so we can give you more precise directions.

I added the code of thumbnail.html

I cannot find any documentation for thumbnail.html on Apple's Developer reference site - can you link to whatever documentation/guide you're using?

I'm not the original developer of this plugin. At some point, likely after a system update (not sure which one), it stopped displaying thumbnails correctly. The only file I have access to for making changes is thumbnail.html, which is responsible for generating the thumbnails in Finder.
I couldn’t find documentation on thumbnail.html either, so I’m not sure what guidelines apply. I can upload the entire plugin if that would help troubleshoot or understand how it’s structured.

So which HTML element is the thumbnail in your code sample? What is it? An  tag or something else?

For example if your original image is a data URI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme I could provide code that will scale the image to given constraints of max width and max height while preserving original aspect ratio and output as a new dataURI, which can then be added to the page HTML using an IMG tag (see above Wikipedia page).

The element generated by code new Graph(domGraph) is canvas, which I can resize using code like graphinstance.resize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight), the problem is to get access to thumbnail width and height inside JS code...

^ @ФилиппЦветков See the image element properties naturalHeight/naturalWidth
